# Attempting to Parse and split hash of URL, complex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I need to grab some information from the URL Hash... but the structure is a little complex and repetitive to easily Regex through... Hoping someone smarter than I can figure this out...

In JS I'm adding selections, which when changed, reload the page with the updated hash... with the page refresh, need to parse the new window location to properly match the selections previously made.

URL is like so:

```
#dynamic/{"sidebar":[{"facetid":8,"data":{"value":"bell"}},{"facetid":9,"data":{"value":"brooks"}}],"searchString":"SearchText","ver":1}
```

```
var parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = window.location.href;
var StringSource = (parser.hash).replace(/%22/g, '"');
(StringSource.split("}",StringSource.length))
```

What I'd really like is an array of objects for the facetid with matching value... and then just a variable for the value of "searchString"...

I'm horrible when it comes to Regex and String manipulation of this level

Comment: can you expect that to be valid JSON every time? there is `JSON.parse` that would provide much more easier to handle structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
var sec = parser.href.split(/\//)
var json = JSON.parse(sec[1])
```

The 1st line separates out the #dynamic from the JSON part

The 2nd line will parse the json part into a usable form for JSON.

Comment: Dude... you rock. this is exactly what I needed

Comment: As a followup, can you explain the /\// for the split? I know it's some RegEx notation, but I'm not able to figure out what it actually means.

Comment: @Blackard Regular expressions in JS have a clean syntax of simply surrounding them with `/` . So if I did this: `/hello/` it would be a RegEx that matches the substring "hello" in any string. Since they are marked by `/`, you can't use an actual `/` character inside them without escaping it first, hence the preceding `\`. So `/\//` is a RegEx that matches a single `/` character. To be fair, though, a RegEx isn't needed for something this simple; you could just use `parser.href.split('/')` and it would work equally well.

Comment: @Blackard We need to separate out the #dynamic/ from the rest of the string. If we split it on the / character, we can isolate the json part out. The split function will return an array with element 0 (sec[0]) being #dynamic and element 1 (sec[1]) being the rest of the string. Then the 2nd line will parse sec[1] into usable JSON. I hope this helps.

Comment: @Blackard If the answer above was helpful, please don't forget to click the checkmark to mark it as the answer. Thank you.